# R segfaulting when reading XML

Tags: r, xml, segmentation-fault, xml2

I have the following XML file

```
<conf>
<Constraints>
<BETA>0</BETA>
</Constraints>
</conf>
```

And when I try to load this xml

```
R> library(XML)
R> xmlParse('test.xml')

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x3a00000000, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("RS_XML_ParseTree", as.character(file), handlers, as.logical(ignoreBlanks),     as.logical(replaceEntities), as.logical(asText), as.logical(trim),     as.logical(validate), as.logical(getDTD), as.logical(isURL),     as.logical(addAttributeNamespaces), as.logical(useInternalNodes),     as.
logical(isHTML), as.logical(isSchema), as.logical(fullNamespaceInfo),     as.character(encoding), as.logical(useDotNames), xinclude,     error, addFinalizer, as.integer(options), as.logical(parentFirst),     PACKAGE = "XML")
 2: xmlParse("test.xml")

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

Is there something I need to assess before loading an xml file in R ?

The xml file seems correct as to syntax (according to a web xml validator)

I created a new file and pasted those few lines and it crashed all the same, so it does not appear to be the file format...

```
R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] XML_3.98-1.4
```

And I tried `xml2`

```
R> library(xml2)
R> read_xml(
x=         encoding=  ...=       as_html=   options=   n=         verbose=   base_url=  
R> read_xml(x = 'test.xml')

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x3a00000000, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("xml2_doc_parse_file", PACKAGE = "xml2", path, encoding,     as_html, options)
 2: doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options)
 3: read_xml.character(x = "test.xml")
 4: read_xml(x = "test.xml")
```

My idea is that the `libXml2` library used by those packages must be at fault here... Though I do not know how to test this

```
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include -I"/pxfs1/home/user/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"/pxfs1/home/user/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/BH/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
```

The libxml2 I have is fairly out of date:

```
$ rpm -qa |grep -i libxml2
libxml2-2.7.6-17.el6_6.1.i686
libxml2-python-2.7.6-17.el6_6.1.x86_64
libxml2-devel-2.7.6-17.el6_6.1.i686
libxml2-2.7.6-17.el6_6.1.x86_64
libxml2-devel-2.7.6-17.el6_6.1.x86_64
```

Comment: Is the backend of the XML package compiled? And how large is your xml file? My first take on the problem would be to use another xml library.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you also posted the whole xml file. A segfault is a hint that a compiled function fails. Both functions that fail do call compiled functions internally. Make sure all your packages are the latest version and a version fitting your R installation. Please post package and R versions.

Comment: Sorry, obviously I'm not very concentrated today, I hope other people are more helpful.

Comment: @hrbrmstr good ! any idea how I can check the libxml2 version that the package is build against (within R) ? Else I'll rebuild and check the build logs

Comment: Well, you're on RedHat, so that means you prbly had to compile either pkg/both pkgs which means you should know what version you have installed. `rpm -qa |grep -i libxml` on the cmdline shld tell you.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I am on centos but same-same, the package only look at includes if I am correct so not indication on which version is it using. thanks for the rpm command, can you give me the version of libxml2 you have ?

Comment: `2.9.4`. You're running a woefully old and very insecure version of `libxml2`. That also likely means the rest of your system is woefully out of date. If so, you have bigger worries than the R crashing bug.

Comment: @hrbmstr Lol I am always surprised to see that sort of comments, have you ever worked in a company with more than 5 people, I'm asking genuinely... You never find up to date software, it is almost a rule to never be running lattest major... We run a centos6 distro which is "prev major"... anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating `libxml2` worked

```
libxml2-python-2.7.6-21.el6_8.1.x86_64        Fri 04 Nov 2016 10:10:17 AM EDT
libxml2-devel-2.7.6-21.el6_8.1.x86_64         Fri 04 Nov 2016 10:10:17 AM EDT
libxml2-devel-2.7.6-21.el6_8.1.i686           Fri 04 Nov 2016 10:10:16 AM EDT
libxml2-2.7.6-21.el6_8.1.x86_64               Fri 04 Nov 2016 10:10:16 AM EDT
libxml2-2.7.6-21.el6_8.1.i686                 Fri 04 Nov 2016 10:10:16 AM EDT
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's a bug in R XML package. We've found that some time age new way of managing references in this package has been introduced (error is on Linux / OS X, not on Windows)

Work around is to install this package with node GC disabled

```
R -e 'install.packages("XML", configure.args=c("--enable-nodegc=no"))
```